# Create array, and add a bunch of stdCLass objects to it

Tags: php, arrays, class, object

Struggling with the basics here.

I want to setup an array, and fill it with multiple data objects, by looping through an array.

How do I add multiple $parent data objects that are unique, to the parentarray?

When I use the below the last one overwrites all the others. As simple as adding $parent[] or something like that?

Thanks,

```
$parentarray = array();
foreach ($otherarray as $bar) {
$parent = new stdClass;
$parent->conversion = $bar;
$parent->negative = $constant;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$parentarray = array();
foreach ($otherarray as $bar) {
    $parent = new stdClass;
    $parent->conversion = $bar;
    $parent->negative = $constant;
    $parentarray[] = $parent; // Or am I mistaken?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use

```
$parentarray[] = $parent;
```

?

Comment: your comment took too long :P

Comment: Spot on - but going by the timestamp on the answer :-) thanks!

Comment: @Dan Actually *this* was first :)