# How do I add/remove an entry to an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that's made up of data returned by a SQL query:

```
$_SESSION['licensed_users'] = $db->get_results("SELECT np.id FROM `new_people` np LEFT JOIN institute.users_roles ur ON np.institute_uid = ur.uid WHERE np.company_id=$company_id AND ur.rid=8 AND np.active = 1");
```

This returns an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 25590 )
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 40657 )
   [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 60685 ) 
   [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 61900 )
   [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65224 )
   [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 65369 ) 
   [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 79171 ) 
   [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 80763 )
   [8] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 80762 ) 
   [9] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 80761 )
 )
```

In another section of the code I loop through the values to see if the current user is part of that array:

```
foreach($_SESSION'licensed_users'] as $key=>$value) {
   if($value->id == $people_id) {
      $is_licensed = true;
   }
}
```

`$is_licensed` is used to determine which set of form fields to display to the user. When the user submits the form, if a certain group of fields is set to a certain value, I need to either add the user ($people_id) to the `$_SESSION['licensed_users']` array if `$is_licensed` is false, or remove them from the array if `$is_licensed` is true. The code for determining which action to take is no problem; I just can't for the life of me remember/figure out how to add to an array of objects. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406128/create-array-and-add-a-bunch-of-stdclass-objects-to-it) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083567/add-to-array-if-it-isnt-there-already), but I already know if the ID is in the array or not; I just need to be able to add or remove it.

(Yes, there is a reason we're using session variables - we need to be able to pass values between pages of the site. It's either that or cookies.)

I've tried `$_SESSION['licensed_users'][] = array("id"=>$people_id);` but it doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Comment: What about making `$db->get_results` not only return an array, but index with their `id` as well. Then you can just do `isset($_SESSION'licensed_users'][$people_id])` to determine if such an entry exists (and you will have that one directly if).

Comment: @hakre - I'm not sure what you mean. How would I force my query to return an array that's indexed by id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove $lu[6]:

```
unset($lu[6]);
```

To add an element:

```
$lu[] = $current_user;
```

Comment: Thanks; I edited the original post while you were answering, so please take a look. Also, your version of adding wouldn't account for the fact that this is an array of objects - the $people_id value needs to be added as an array with the key of `id`.

Comment: In that case, you'd just make $current_user an object with the data you want. $current_user can be anything. If you're looking for shorthand for converting an array to an object, you can try `$current_user = (object)array('id'=>$people_id)`.

Comment: I've tried this: `$add_person = (object)array('id'=>$people_id);
    $_SESSION['licensed_users'][] = $add_person;`. It doesn't work; no errors, just doesn't update the array. What am I doing wrong?